# Password Reset on AIX machine trouble

Tags: password, aix, non-root-user

Im trying to reset a user password locally using the root account. The user is adam. Everything looks ok when I type in passwd adam using the root account. It prompts me to enter new password, enter the new password again.

Afterwards, When I putty in to the server and login in as adam using the new password, I get access denied. How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you show us the user's `/etc/passwd` file entry?

Comment: adam:!:214:1031:Adam:/home/adam:/usr/bin/ksh @JuliePelletier

Comment: Logon & rlogin set to true ?

Comment: Account locked by virtue of unsuccessful login counts?

Answer (score 3):

The right fix for this situation is to reset the unsuccessful login counts for the user, not to disable a security feature.

Run:

```
chuser unsuccessful_login_count=0 adam
```

to clear the unsuccessful login counts for adam, and:

```
chuser account_locked=false adam
```

if needed (see if the account is locked with: `lsuser -a account_locked adam`).

Answer (score -4):

Solved the issue. Add `loginretries = 0` to `/etc/security/users` file

Comment: That's like saying you solved your problem unlocking the front door by removing the lock.