# reset failed login count / unlock aix/UNIX account

Tags: command-line, aix, accounts

As system administrator it is necessary to lock / unlock users or to reset failed login count.

let's look how we can perform  lock / unlock users or to reset on UNIX/AIX

Comment: Seems to me to be a duplicate of: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/306499/117549

Answer (score 11):

- Fist become root:

  ```
    su - root
    lsuser -a unsuccessful_login_count userid
  ```
- reset unsuccessful login count:

  ```
    chsec -f /etc/security/lastlog -a unsuccessful_login_count=0 -s userid
  ```
- unlock account:

  ```
    chuser account_locked=false userid
  ```
- to lock an AIX account:

  ```
    chuser account_locked=true userid
  ```
- check if locked:

  ```
    lsuser userid
  ```

For Linux like redhat distros

```
pam_tally2 --user=test1
pam_tally2 --user=test1 --reset
```